# Razor debug returns 404 when launched in webbroswer

Tags: razor, http-status-code-404

I've added a view in my views, with layout and stuff. But when I launch the page through Visual Studio (or directly address the URL), the page gives a 404 error:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the page in my config file, fixed now.